# Cannot read file of a supplementary group

Tags: permissions, filesystems, security, users

I have two groups manually created in `/etc/group`:

```
file-owner:x:300:user
user:x:400:
```

I have a configuration file, owned by the user/group `file-owner`. I don't want other users to read it.

```
 ls -l /tmp/my-configs.txt         
 -r--r-----   1   file-owner     file-owner     1054552  Jun 11  12:22  /tmp/my-configs.txt
```

I run a process with id `user:user` but I cannot read the configuration file owned by `file-owner`. An example error message, from`cat`: `/tmp/my-configs.txt: Permission denied`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In that user:user session, does `groups` display `file-owner`? If not, you may not have logged in afresh. Alternatively, is SELinux preventing access to the file? The actual error message (from, e.g. `cat /tmp/my-configs.txt`) would also be useful.

Comment: What about the `groups` question, above?

Comment: @JeffSchaller It is answered on the question body above

Comment: I haven't communicated clearly; I'm wondering if the "user" login session *actually has* the 'file-owner' group associated with it. The `groups` command as "user" would illustrate that (one way or the other).